# Socket C: broadcast with select, send Server Response to all Clients

Tags: c, sockets, select, client-server, broadcast

I'm sorry but I'm a beginner in C Socket Programming. I have a Server and more client. When a Client send a message to the Server, the Server should forward this message to all Clients.
I designed Server and Client using the Select(), now I don't know how I can do to send in broadcast the message to all Clients, in broadcast way.
This is my Server side called SelectServer.c:

```html
#include "Header.h"
#include "Utility.h"

/**
variabili globale client sockets array
rappresenta l'array di socket descriptor connessi ai client TCP
*/
int conn_set[SIZE]; 



/**
@brief aggiunge la nuova connessione all'array di client connessi
@param sockfd, il socket della nuova connessione
@param conn_set, ptr all'array delle connessioni
@param dim, dimensione dell'array
@return true se la nuova connessione è stata registrata, false se la coda è piena
*/
bool add_client(int sockfd, int *conn_set, int dim){
 
 int i = 0;
 bool is_registered = false;
 for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
 {
  if (conn_set[i] == -1)
  {
   conn_set[i] = sockfd;
   is_registered = true;
   break;
  }
 }

 return is_registered;
}


/**
@brief Funzione che gestisce l'arrivo di nuove connessioni sul listening socket TCP.
@param sockT - listening TCP socket del server
@return intero:
-# pari a -1 se la connessione è stata rifiutata.
-# pari al socket descriptor della nuova connessione (se correttamente inserita in elenco)
*/
int handleNewConn(int sockT){

 struct sockaddr_storage client; 
 socklen_t sslen = sizeof(client);

 int conn = accept(sockT, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sslen);
 if (conn == -1)
 {
  perror("accept() error: ");
  return -1;
 }

 printf("TCP listening socket accepted new connection from ");
 printAddressInfo((struct sockaddr *)&client, sslen);
 printf("\n");

 bool is_added = add_client(conn, conn_set, SIZE);
 if (is_added == false)
 {
  printf("max client queue\n");
  close(conn);
  return -1;
 }

return conn;
}


/** 
@brief Inizializza l'array dei socket connessi
@param conn_set, ptr all'arrayd di interi
@param dim, dimensione dell'array
*/
void setConnSet(int *conn_set, int dim){

 int i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
 {
  conn_set[i] = -1;
 }
}


/**
@brief Funzione di utilità
@param name, nome dell'eseguibile
*/
void usage(char *name){
 printf("Usage: %s <domain>\n", name);
 printf("\tdomain: 0 (UNSPEC), 4 (INET), 6 (INET6)\n");
} 



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 
 //*********************
 char buf2[50000];
 int posxy[2]; 
 int pos[100][100];
 int x, y;
 //*********************
 

 if (argc != 2) 
 {
  usage(argv[0]);
  return INVALID;
 }
 
 int family = getFamily(argv[1]);
 
 
 int sockT = 0; //TCP listening socket
 int sockU = 0; //UDP listening socket
 
 sockT = passiveOpen(family, NULL, SERVICEPORT, SOCK_STREAM); 
 sockU = passiveOpen(family, NULL, SERVICEPORT, SOCK_DGRAM); 
 
 
 if ((sockT == -1) || (sockU == -1))
 {
  printf("Errore nell'avviare i socket\n");
  return ERROR;
 } 
 
 /* su Mac OS X: 
 $ netstat -a | grep 49152
 tcp4       0      0  *.49152                *.*                    LISTEN     
 udp4       0      0  *.49152                *.*                            
 */
 printf("TCP Server and UDP server running on port %s\n", SERVICEPORT);

 //inizializzo l'array
 setConnSet(conn_set, SIZE); 

 //handle delle nuove connessioni (socket connessi)
 int conn = 0; 

 //protocol-independent management of connections
 struct sockaddr_storage client; 
 socklen_t sslen = sizeof(client);


 /*
 definiamo il set dei file descriptor da monitorare:
 il server sarà in attesa di:
 - connessioni 
 - messaggi, 
 - e tutte condizioni monitorabili in lettura
 */

 //dichiaro 2 read file descriptor set
 fd_set rset, allset; 

 FD_ZERO(&rset); //azzero set descrittori
 FD_ZERO(&allset); //azzero set descrittori copia

 FD_SET(sockT, &rset); //aggiungo socket TCP
 FD_SET(sockU, &rset); //aggiungo socket UDP

 //prendo il max tra i 2, più 1
 int max = (sockT > sockU)?sockT+1: sockU+1; 

 //duplico il set - allset contiene sempre i 2 socket TCP ed UDP
 allset = rset; 
 
 //***************
 ssize_t n = 0;
 //***************
 
 int result = 0;
 int quit = 0;
 while (!quit)
 {
  /*
  rfds è un value-result argument, modificato da select():
  dobbiamo re-inizializzarlo
  */
  FD_ZERO(&rset);
  rset = allset; 

  //wait for select forever
  result = select(max, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  if (result == -1)
  {
   perror("select() error: ");
   continue;
  }
  else if (result == 0)
  { 
   //timeout su select (non specificato, non dovrei mai arrivarci)
   continue; 
  } 
  else 
  {
   //result è pari al numero di descriptor pronti in lettura...
   printf("%d socket ready for reading\n", result);

   

   //verifichiamo chi ha dati da leggere...
   if ( FD_ISSET(sockU, &rset))
   {
   
   //*******
   n = recv(sockU, posxy, sizeof(posxy), 0);
     printf ("Prova %d",posxy[0]);
   //******
    printf("Received a datagram...\n");
    handleUDPMessage(sockU);
    //printf("decrement result...\n");
    result--;
   }

   if ( FD_ISSET(sockT, &rset))
   {
    //new TCP Connection 
    conn = handleNewConn(sockT);
   
    if (conn != -1)
    { 
     //printf("add new conn to allset\n");
     FD_SET(conn, &allset);
    
     if ( (conn + 1) > max)
      max = conn+1;
    }
    result--;
   }

   if (result == 0)
   {
    //skip the rest
    continue;
   }

   //a questo punto devo controllare tutte le connessioni attive dei client
   int j = 0; //indice dell'array di connessioni TCP client
   while (result > 0)
   {
    if ( (conn_set[j] != -1)  && FD_ISSET(conn_set[j], &rset))
    {
     
     printf("Client Connection number %d ready for reading ...\n", j);
     int status = handleTCPClient(conn_set[j]);

     //decremento result
     result--;

     if (status == 0)
     { 
      //client ha chiuso la connessione
      close(conn_set[j]);

      //rimuovo il socket dal set da monitorare
      FD_CLR(conn_set[j], &allset);

      //libero la sua posizione nell'array
      conn_set[j] = -1;
     }//fi status
    }//fi FD_ISSET
    
    //passo al prossimo elemento dell'array di connessioni TCP 
    j++;
   }//wend client connection

  }//fi result

 }//wend
 
 //never here
 close(sockT);
 close(sockU);
 
return 0;
}
```

This is my Client side called SelectClient.c:

```html
#include "Header.h"
#include "Utility.h"


/**
@brief Utility function
@param name, nome dell'eseguibile
*/
void usage(char *name){
 printf("Usage: %s <servername> <protocol> <domain>\n", name);
 printf("\tprotocol= TCP aut UDP;\n");
 printf("\tdomain= 0 (UNSPEC), 4(INET), 6(INET6)\n"); 
}


/**
@brief Esegue l'I/O multiplexing su stdin e socket connesso (UDP/TCP)
@param sock, il socket da monitorare
@param type, tipo di socket
@return nulla
*/
void multiplex(int sock, int type){

//*******************************
 int pos[100][100];
 int posxy[2];
 int x,y,xx,yy;
 char movimento;
 
 for(x=0;x<100;x++)
  for(y=0;y<100; y++)
   pos[x][y]=0;
   
 time_t tt;

   
   /* Intializes random number generator */
   srand((unsigned) time(&tt));
   
   xx = rand() % 50;
   yy = rand() % 50;
   printf("xx vale %d, yy vale %d",xx,yy);
   pos[xx][yy] = 1;
 
 
 printf("MAPPA INIZIALE:\n");
 for(x=0;x<100;x++)
  for(y=0;y<100; y++)
    printf("%d",pos[x][y]);
//*******************************    
    
    
    
 
 printf("Insert messages for server\n");
 
 fd_set rset; 
 FD_ZERO(&rset);
 
 FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rset);
 FD_SET(sock, &rset);
 
 int max = (sock > STDIN_FILENO)? sock: STDIN_FILENO;

 struct timeval timer;
 timer.tv_sec = 5;
 timer.tv_usec = 0;
 
 int result = 0;
 bool quit = false;
 
 //predispongo la comunicazione ed il file descriptor set da monitorare
 ssize_t n = 0;
 char msg[BUFSIZE] = "";
 
 //***********************************
 int msgpos[100][100];
 char msgposc[50000] = "";
 
 //***********************************
 
 while (!quit)
 {
  result = select(max+1, &rset, NULL, NULL, &timer);
  
  if (result == -1)
  {
   perror("select() error: ");
   break;
  } 
  
  if (result == 0)
  {
   //printf("select timeout\n");
  }
  
  if (result > 0)
  {
   if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rset))
   {
    if (fgets(msg, BUFSIZE-1, stdin) != NULL)
    {
    //**************************
    printf("scrivi\n");
    //scanf("%c",&movimento);
    movimento = getchar();
    printf("movimento %c\n",movimento);
 
    if(movimento == 'j'){
      printf("destra\n");
      pos[xx][yy] = 0;
      yy++;
      printf("xx vale %d, yy vale %d",xx,yy);
      pos[xx][yy] = 1;
      }
    else if(movimento == 'h'){
      printf("sinistra\n");
      pos[xx][yy] = 0;
      yy--;
      printf("xx vale %d, yy vale %d",xx,yy);
      pos[xx][yy] = 1;
      }
    else if(movimento == 'u'){
      printf("sopra\n");
      pos[xx][yy] = 0;
      xx++;
      printf("xx vale %d, yy vale %d",xx,yy);
      pos[xx][yy] = 1;
     }
    else if(movimento == 'n'){
      printf("sotto\n");
      pos[xx][yy] = 0;
      xx--;
      printf("xx vale %d, yy vale %d",xx,yy);
      pos[xx][yy] = 1;
      }
    else
     printf("Non hai inserito un comando valido\n");
 
    for(x=0;x<100;x++)
     for(y=0;y<100; y++)
      printf("%d",pos[x][y]);
 
    //snprintf(msgposc, 50000, "%d", pos);
 
   //snprintf(posx, 10, "%d", xx);
    //snprintf(posy, 10, "%d", yy);

 
    //printf("PROVAaa: %s \n", posx);
 
 
    posxy[0] = xx;
    posxy[1] = yy;
    //**************************
     /*
     fgets ritorna una stringa che termina con la sequenza
     '\n\0'
     il null-terminated non è contato da strlen,
     ma '\n' si.
     Per tagliare '\n' trasmetto (strlen(msg) - 1).
     
     @note: ATTENZIONE
     Ogni volta che premo "Return" (dò invio), fgets() ritorna una stringa è vuota.
     La stringa vuota viene letta da send che trasmette 0 bytes dal socket "sock".
     Dobbiamo distinguere 2 casi:
     - se sock è di tipo SOCK_STREAM, l'operazione non genera dati da trasmettere;
     - se sock è di tipo SOCK_DGRAM, l'operazione genera un datagram UDP vuoto, che viene inviato al server UDP
     
     Per eliminare questo scenario, possiamo effettuare send solo su stringhe non vuote.
     */
     //if ( (strlen(msg) - 1) != 0){
      n = send(sock, posxy, sizeof(posxy), 0);
      //n = send(sock, msg, strlen(msg) - 1, 0);
      printf("sent %d bytes\n", (int)n);
     //}//fi
    }
    else
     break; //chiusura
   }
   
   
   if (FD_ISSET(sock, &rset))
   {
    //n = recv(sock, msg, BUFSIZE-1, 0);
    //******************************
    n = recv(sock, posxy, sizeof(posxy), 0);
    //*******************************
    if (n == -1)
    {
     perror("recv() error: ");
     close(sock);
     return; // ERROR;
    }
    else if (n > 0)
    {
     //**************************
     msg[n] = 0;
     msgpos[n][n]=0;
     printf("mappa:\n");
     printf("server reply: '%d'\n", posxy[0]);
     //**************************
    // msg[n] = 0;
    // printf("\tResponse %d bytes message '%s'\n", (int)n, msg);
    }
    else
    { 
     //n==0 over TCP: closed connection
     //if (type == SOCK_STREAM)
     // break;
     
     /*
     In realtà non abbiamo necessità di usare il parametro type in input alla funzione,
     perché il tipo del socket può essere ottenuto leggendo le opzioni del socket:
     */ 
     int sockType = 0;
     socklen_t optlen = sizeof(sockType);
     if ( getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &sockType, &optlen) == 0){
      if (sockType == SOCK_STREAM) {
       printf("This is a TCP socket that received a FIN segment\n");
       break;
      } else {
       printf("This is an UDP socket that received an empty datagram\n");
      } 
     }//fi getsockopt 
        
    }
   
    
      
   }//fi sock
  }//fi result

  FD_ZERO(&rset);
  FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rset);
  FD_SET(sock, &rset);
  max = (sock > STDIN_FILENO)? sock: STDIN_FILENO;

  timer.tv_sec = 5;
  timer.tv_usec = 0;
 }//wend
 printf("Multiplex ended\n");
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 if (argc != 4)
 {
  usage(argv[0]);
  return INVALID;
 }
 
 int family = getFamily(argv[3]); 
 
 int type = 0;
 if ((strcmp(argv[2], "TCP") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[2],"tcp") == 0))
 {
  type = SOCK_STREAM;
 }
 else if (strcmp(argv[2], "UDP") == 0 || (strcmp(argv[2],"udp") == 0))
 {
  type = SOCK_DGRAM;
 }
 else
 {
  printf("Invalid service type\n");
  return FAILURE;
 }

 int sockfd = open_socket(family, argv[1], SERVICEPORT, type);
 if (sockfd == INSUCCESS)
 {
  printf("Errore nell'aprire il socket e stabilire la connessione al server (TCP only)\n");
  return ERROR;
 }

 //ho un socket CONNESSO verso la destinazione specificata:
 struct sockaddr destination;
 socklen_t len = sizeof(destination);
 int res = getpeername(sockfd, &destination, &len);
 if (res != 0) {
  close(sockfd);
  return FAILURE;
 }
 //visualizzo il remote address
 printf("Connected to remote address: ");
 printAddressInfo(&destination, len);
 printf("\n");

 
 multiplex(sockfd, type);

 printf("Closing the socket...\n");
 close(sockfd);

return 0;
}
```

This is Utility.c (where are implemented some functions):

```html
/**
@addtogroup Group11
@{
*/
/**
@file  Utility.c
@author Catiuscia Melle

@brief  Implementazione di funzioni di utilità.

*/

#include "Utility.h"


void printAddressInfo(struct sockaddr * addr, socklen_t len){
 
 //no reverse lookup in getnameinfo
 int niflags = NI_NUMERICSERV | NI_NUMERICHOST;
 char IP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
 char port[PORT_STRLEN] = "";
 
 //visualizzo l'indirizzo locale del socket
 int rv = getnameinfo(addr, len, IP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN, port, PORT_STRLEN, niflags);
 
 if (rv == 0)
 {
  printf("'%s:%s'", IP, port);
 }
 else
 {
  printf("getnameinfo() error: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
 }
}





int open_socket(int family, char *hostname, char *servicename, int type){

 int sockfd = 0; //valore di ritorno della funzione
 int result = 0;
 
 struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
  
 memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); //azzero hints
  
 hints.ai_family = family; //richiedo la risoluzione per IPv6
 hints.ai_socktype = type; //service type
 
 /*
 Se richiedo AF_INET6 come family, 
 allora specificando il flag AI_V4MAPPED, 
 getaddrinfo() deve ritornare l'IPv4-mapped IPv6 address 
 se non trova indirizzi IPv6. 
 Diversamente, l'opzione non è presa in considerazione
 */
 hints.ai_flags = AI_V4MAPPED;
 
 result = getaddrinfo(hostname, servicename, &hints, &res);
 if (result != 0)
 {
  printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(result));
  return INSUCCESS; 
 }
 
 printf("Resolution for: %s:%s Done!\n", hostname, servicename);
 
 for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
 {
  sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
  if (sockfd == -1)
  { 
   perror("socket() error: ");
   continue; 
  }
  //TCP o UDP, il socket viene comunque connesso al destination address
  result = connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);
  if (result == -1)
  {
   perror("connect() error: ");
   close(sockfd);
   continue;
  }

 break;
 }//for

 if (p == NULL) //if (!p)
 {
  printf("Connessione al server %s:%s fallita\n", hostname, servicename);
  return INSUCCESS; 
 }

 //dealloco risorse resolver
 freeaddrinfo(res);

return sockfd;
}



int getFamily(char *param){
 int family = 0;
 if (strncmp(param, "4", 1) == 0){
  family = AF_INET;
 } else if (strncmp(param, "6", 1) == 0){
  family = AF_INET6;
 } else {
  family = AF_UNSPEC;
 } 
 return family;
}








/*************************************************************************/ 

int passiveOpen(int family, char *nodename, char *servicename, int socktype) {

 int sock = INSUCCESS; 
 int result = 0;

 struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;

 memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

 hints.ai_family = family;
 hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; 
 hints.ai_socktype = socktype;

 hints.ai_flags |= AI_V4MAPPED;
 hints.ai_flags |= AI_NUMERICSERV;

 result = getaddrinfo(nodename, servicename, &hints, &res);
 if (result != 0)
 {
  printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(result));
  return INSUCCESS;
 }

 int reuse = 1; //opzione SO_REUSEADDR

 for (p = res; p != NULL ; p = p->ai_next)
 {
  sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
  if (sock == -1)
  {
   perror("socket() error: ");
   continue; 
  }
  
  /*
  Per un socket nel dominio AF_INET6, se l'opzione IPV6_V6ONLY è abilitata
  viene meno la compatilibità con IPv4: il socket accetterà comunicazioni solo se
  provenienti da nodi IPv6 (ritornando l'errore 'connection refused' al client che 
  cerca di connettersi).
  Altrimenti, al socket sono consegnati anche datagram IPv4.
  
  Per abilitare l'opzione:
  */ 
     
     int v6flag = 1;
     if (v6flag == 1)
     {
      //turn-on V6ONLY option
      if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6 && setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &v6flag, sizeof(v6flag)) < 0) 
      {
       close(sock);
          continue;
   }
  }
  
  if ( setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0 )
  {
   perror("setsockopt() error: ");
   continue;
  }


  result = bind(sock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);
  if (result == -1)
  {
   perror("bind() error: ");
   close(sock);
   continue;
  }

  break;
 }//for
 
 if (p == NULL) 
 {
  printf("Non siamo riusciti ad avviare il server %s:%s per il servizio %d\n", nodename, servicename, socktype);
  sock = INSUCCESS;
 }

 //dealloco le risorse
 freeaddrinfo(res);

 if (socktype == SOCK_STREAM)
 {
  //TCP passive open 
  result = listen(sock, BACKLOG);
  if (result == -1)
  {
   perror("listen() error: ");
   close(sock);
   return INSUCCESS;
  }
 }

return sock;
}




void handleUDPMessage(int sockU){
 
 //protocol-independent addresses management
 struct sockaddr_storage client; 
 socklen_t sslen = sizeof(client);
 
 char msg[BUFSIZE] = "";
 ssize_t n = 0;
 
 
 int posxy[2];
 
 
 
 //n = recvfrom(sockU, msg, BUFSIZE-1 , 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sslen);
 //*******************
 n = recvfrom(sockU, posxy, sizeof(posxy), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sslen);
 //*****************
 if (n < 0)
 {
  perror("error on recvfrom(): ");
  return;
 }
 
 printAddressInfo((struct sockaddr *)&client, sslen);
 msg[n] = '\0';
 //printf("Received UDP %d bytes message '%s'\n", (int)n, msg);
 printf("Received UDP %d bytes message '%d'\n", (int)n, posxy[0]);

  
 char c = toupper(msg[n-1]);
 msg[n-1] = toupper(msg[0]); 
 msg[0] = c;
 
 printf("Reply to msg\n");
 //n = sendto(sockU, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sslen);
 n = sendto(sockU, posxy, sizeof(posxy), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sslen);
 if (n == -1)
 {
  perror("sendto() error: ");
 }
 
return;
}



int handleTCPClient(int sock){
 
 char msg[BUFSIZE] = "";
 ssize_t n = 0;
 
 
 int posxy[2];
 
 
 
 //get the message from client
 //n = recv(sock, msg, BUFSIZE-1, 0);
 n = recv(sock, posxy, sizeof(posxy), 0);
 
 if (n > 0)
 {
  //protocol-independent management of connections
  struct sockaddr_storage client; 
  socklen_t sslen = sizeof(client);
  char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
  char portstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
  
  getpeername(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sslen);
  
  
  int niflags = NI_NUMERICSERV | NI_NUMERICHOST;
  int res = getnameinfo( (struct sockaddr *)&client, sslen, \
       ipstr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN, portstr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN, niflags);
  
  if (res == 0)
  {
   printf("Received TCP message from client da %s:%s\n", ipstr, portstr);
  }
  
  msg[n] = '\0';
  //printf("\tmessage '%s'\n\t%d bytes\n",  msg, (int)n);
  printf("\tmessage '%d'\n\t%d bytes\n",  posxy[0], (int)n);
  
  msg[0] = toupper(msg[0]);
  msg[n/2] = toupper(msg[n/2]); 
  msg[n-1] = toupper(msg[n-1]); 
  //n = send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
  n = send(sock, posxy, sizeof(posxy), 0);
  if (n == -1)
  {
   perror("send() error: ");
  }
 return 1;
 }
 
 if (n == 0)
 {
  printf("il client ha chiuso la connessione\n");
  return 0;
 } 
 
 
 if (n < 0)
 {
  perror("error on recv(): ");
  return -1;
 }
    
    return -1;
}
```

and these are my libraries called Utility.h and Header.h:

```html
/**
@addtogroup Group11
@{
*/
/**
@file  Utility.h
@author Catiuscia Melle

@brief  Interfaccia del modulo di funzioni di utilità.

*/

#ifndef __UTILITY_H__
#define __UTILITY_H__


#include "Header.h"


/**
@brief Utility function per la visualizzazione dell'indirizzo associato ad un socket,
protocol-independent
@param addr, ptr alla struct sockaddr da leggere
@param len, dimensione della struttura puntata da addr
@return nulla
*/
void printAddressInfo(struct sockaddr * addr, socklen_t len);

/**
@brief Utility per l'apertura di un connection socket TCP IPv6
@param family - ipv4 o ipv6 protocol family domain...
@param hostname - stringa contenente l'hostname per cui è invocato il resolver 
@param servicename - stringa contenente il service name per cui è invocato il resolver
@param type - intero pari al tipo di socket SOCK_STREAM o SOCK_DGRAM
@return intero, pari al socket descriptor creato (-1 in caso di errore).

Attenzione, restituisce sempre un socket connesso (UDP e TCP)
*/
int open_socket(int family, char *hostname, char *servicename, int type);


/**
@brief Legge il valore di param e ritorna l'Address Family corrispondente
@param param, contiene il valore di argv[] corrispondente al dominio inserito.
@return il valore di Address Family corrispondente al dominio specificato
*/
int getFamily(char *param);








/**
@brief Funzione per la hostname resolution che ritorna il socket descriptor per un server.

@param nodename -  hostname da risolvere
@param servicename - indirizzo del servizio
@param socktype - tipo di sock (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM)
@return intero pari al socket descriptor allocato o -1 in caso di errore

*/
int passiveOpen(int family, char *nodename, char *servicename, int socktype);

/**
@brief Funzione che gestisce l'arrivo di messaggi sul socket UDP in ascolto
@param sockU - socket UDP in ascolto
@return nulla

Effettua ricezione ed invio al client UDP. Usa <em>getnameinfo()</em> per recuperare 
l'indirizzo del client UDP. 

*/
void handleUDPMessage(int sockU);


/**
@brief Funzione che gestisce l'arrivo di nuovi messaggi su connessioni TCP.
@param sock - socket TCP della connessione client pronta.
@return intero:
-# pari a -1 in caso di errore;
-# pari a 0 se la connessione è stata chiusa;
-# pari a 1 se il messaggio è stato elaborato con successo.
*/
int handleTCPClient(int sock);

#endif
/** @} */
```

```html
/**
@addtogroup Group11
@{
*/
/**
@file  Header.h
@author Catiuscia Melle

@brief  Header comune al client e server dell'esempio

L'header definisce costanti comuni al client e server.
*/

#ifndef __HEADER_H__
#define __HEADER_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h> //resolver related functions

#include <sys/types.h> //necessario su Mac
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ctype.h> //toupper()
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PORTNUMBER   49152   /**< TCP listening port, decimal */
#define SERVICEPORT  "49152"  /**< TCP listening port, name */
#define PORT_STRLEN 6 /**< lunghezza di una stringa rappresentativa di un indirizzo di trasporto */

#define BACKLOG 10  /**< dimensione della coda di connessioni */

#define SIZE 15 /**< dimensione della coda di connessioni concorrenti gestite dal server */

#define BUFSIZE 512 /**< dimensione del buffer di messaggio */

#define FAILURE 3  /**< definizione del valore di errore di ritorno del processo in caso di errori delle Sockets API */

#define INVALID 5  /**< se i due processi non sono avviati col giusto numero di parametri */

#define ERROR 1 /**<  valore di errore */

#define INSUCCESS -1 /**< valore di ritorno non valido */


#endif /* __HEADER_H__ */

/** @} */
```

In particular, look that the message that I send from Client to Server is called "posxy". The Server receive "posxy", print it and send it again to the client who sent. But if I open more Client, the Server send "posxy" only at the Client who sent it, I want to send "posxy" from Server al all Clients connected.

I hope that somebody can help me.

Comment: Please reduce your problem to the essential part instead of expecting everybody to read lots of code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And in general: TCP (which you use) does not support broadcasts. This means you have to send the message to each of the clients manually.

Comment: No no..I use TCP and UDP. It is specified when I start the file..in this way: ./SelectC localhost UDP 4